# 400 Bad Request (NodeJs) Post Data from NodeJs to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, http

I have these codes but I can't find what is wrong? I've been searching for an answer for about 2 hours now. I hope you can help me.

This is my code...

```js
const parameters = {
   record1: "sample1",
   record2: "sample2" 
};

const post_data = querystring.stringify(parameters);

const options = {
  host: "mywebsite.com",
  port: "80",
  path: "post/record.php",
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
}

const request = http.request(options, (response)=>{
  let chunks_of_data = [];
            
  response.on('data', (fragments) => {
    chunks_of_data.push(fragments);
  });
            
  response.on('end', () => {
    let response_body = Buffer.concat(chunks_of_data);
    console.log(response_body.toString());
  });
            
  response.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
});
            
request.on('error', (error) => {
  console.log('Error Code: ' + error.code);
  console.log('Error Message: ' + error.message);
});
            
request.write(post_data);
request.end();
```

And this is the PHP source code...

```js
<?php
$host = "localhost";  
$user = "root";  
$password = "";  
$db_name = "sample_db"; 

$serverconn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db_name) or die("ConnectionError");

$record1 = $_POST['record1'];
$record2 = $_POST['record2'];

$sqlsign = "UPDATE sample_db SET record1 = '$record1', record2 = '$record2' WHERE id = '1';";  
$resultsign = mysqli_query($serverconn, $sqlsign);
if(!$resultsign)
{
    echo "Failed";
}
else
{
    echo "Success";
}
?>
```

When I RUN the NodeJs code, here is what I received...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
<title> 400 Bad Request
</title></head>
<body style="color: #444; margin:0;font: normal 14px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; height:100%; background-color: #fff;">
<div style="height:auto; min-height:100%; ">     <div style="text-align: center; width:800px; margin-left: -400px; position:absolute; top: 30%; left:50%;">
        <h1 style="margin:0; font-size:150px; line-height:150px; font-weight:bold;">400</h1>
<h2 style="margin-top:20px;font-size: 30px;">Bad Request
</h2>
<p>It is not a valid request!</p>
</div></div></body></html>
```

I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: probably, request.end() closes the requested before it is read properly... try removing it and testing. Then try adding it, but in a better way this time (I don't know that better way)

Answer (score 0):

Your more is supposed to be fixed by adding a `/` before the path. Like this -

`path: "/post/record.php"`

Comment: Still doesn't work. The result shows HTML format and it says "301 Moved Permanently" error.